# Powerbuilder report changes with display text size

Tags: printing, report, powerbuilder, text-size

(Powerbuilder 11.5.1 build 5097)

I have found that the text size setting (Windows7 Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Display "Change Text Size") alters *printed reports* coming from powerbuilder.

- When set to smaller - 100% (default), the report works as designed
- When set to Medium - %125, 33 rows of data take up nearly one full extra printed line and get cut off.
- When set to Large - %150, the report works as designed again.

All my testing is being done with the same computer using the same printer changing just this one widnows preference.  The report contains a fixed-size box which takes up most of the right half of the page.  When I print using "medium fonts" the bottom of the data gets cut off.  Folding over the page and comparing it to a "smaller font" print shows that the report block is exactly the same size but the data within it is drifting downwards.

Call me old fashioned but I firmly believe that the display settings of my monitor should not affect prints.  Anyone have any information on how to make powerbuilder behave correctly?

Comment: Do you have any code in your application that resizes datawindows based on the screen resolution?

Comment: No, no resize at all.  The report contains several boxed results that retrieve their X,Y,Height,Width from a database table.  Those properties are applied to the subreports using DataWindow.Modify(...)

Comment: I just re-performed my side-by-side overlay test and I am seeing that on the "bad" print the box grew (a little) and the text slowly took more and more space (more than the growth of the box).  So it seems that the display property is affecting some measurement or conversion.  All of these reports and subreports are in the default powerbuilder units because I recall having a bad day when I tried to change them to 1/1000 of centimeters.